# Resetting form to its values set originally

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form, where I am setting default value on dropdown item in a get call:

```html
<form class="col-md-5 location-seachform" name="loctionForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f);" novalidate  >
   <select class="form-control" name="somename" [(ngModel)]="criterialDefaultVal" >
     <option [value]="ii" [attr.selected]="ii==0 ? '' : null" *ngFor="let loc_crit of objectKeys(somecriteria); let ii= index"> {{somecriteria[loc_crit] }} 
     </option>
   <select>
  <button class="btn btn--filled pull-right" type="submit"><span class="btn__copy"><span class="btn__label">Search</span></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn--filled pull-right" (click)="formReset(f)" type="button"><span class="btn__copy"><span class="btn__label">Clear</span></span></button>
</form>
```

so here `[(ngModel)]="criterialDefaultVal"` is for setting default value. Now I also have a 'Clear' button for clearing out ANY CHANGES i I make to the dropdown default value. For that I used this:

```js
formReset(ResetFormVal){
    ResetFormVal.form.reset()
}
```

Now when I click on clear button, it 'resets' even those values that I set originally, making the select as blank; whereas I want to reset only the changed values. Please help.

Comment: Read the documentation: it explains what the method does (it's not what you think it does), and what arguments you can pass to make it do what you want. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset

Answer (score 0):

reset() method clear all the values.
store initial value of form in a variable and set these values instead of resetting the form on click.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, reset will just clear your form.

What I suggest you do instead is one of the following:

Create a FormModel class which contains all of your form properties. In this case:

```
class FormModel {
    criterialDefaultVal: string;
}
```

In your component, maintain two properties

```
originalFormValue: FormModel;
currentFormValue: FormModel;
```

In your init function set the currentFormValue from a clone of the original

```
this.currentFormValue = Object.assign({}, this.originalFormValue);
```

In your reset, do the same thing. This will deep clone the value, without pointing to the same reference, and will restore your values to the original.

```
this.currentFormValue = Object.assign({}, this.originalFormValue);
```

Last but not least, in your html you should refer to the `currentFormValue?.criterialDefaultVal`